# view output of already running processes in linux

Tags: linux, process, ps

I have a process that is running in the background (sh script) and I wonder if it is possible to view the output of this process without having to interrupt it.

The process ran by some application otherwise I would have attached it to a screen for later viewing. It might take an hour to finish and i want to make sure it's running normally with no errors.

Comment: What type of output is it? Is it plain text? If so you can just use "tail -f <output file>". The tail gets the end of the file, the -f flag tells it to "follow" the file. There are other options to the tail command to specify how many lines and I think how long to wait between polling the file.

Comment: The problem is, i did not start this process it started by some application the provider has launched (cpanel installer) and no they did not redirect the output to any file otherwise i would have just used tail like you suggested, that in mind is there a way to view the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already an program that uses ptrace(2) in linux to do this, **retty**:

http://pasky.or.cz/dev/retty/

It works if your running program is already attached to a tty, I do not know if it will work if you run your program in background.

At least it may give some good hints. :)

You can probably retreive the exit code from the program using `ptrace(2)`, otherwise just attach to the process using `gdb -p <pid>`, and it will be printed when the program dies.

You can also manipulate file descriptors using gdb:

```
(gdb) p close(1)
$1 = 0
(gdb) p creat("/tmp/stdout", 0600)
$2 = 1
```

http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/

Answer (score 1):

You could try to hook into the `/proc/[pid]/fd/[012]` triple, but likely that won't work.

Next idea that pops to my mind is `strace -p [pid]`, but you'll get "prittified" output. The possible solution is to strace yourself by writing a tiny program using `ptrace(2)` to hook into `write(2)` and writing the data somewhere. It **will work** but is not done in just a few seconds, especially if you're not used to C programming.

Unfortunately I can't think of a program that does precisely what you want, which is why I give you a hint of how to write it yourself. Good luck!